# Touch Scroll List for jquery mobile

Tags: android, listview, jquery-mobile, touch, overflow

I have a html page.

It is targeted for Mobile devices.

I am looking at the listview demos on the Jquery web site.

I would like the User to scroll up and down this list with touch but I cannot seem to get it to work.

I thought just including the jquery mobile framework it would this do this automatically for me?

This is my mark-up:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll, overflow-x: hidden; height: 150px;">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
        <li><a href="acura.html">Acura</a></li>
        <li><a href="audi.html">Audi</a></li>
        <li><a href="bmw.html">BMW</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: overflow-y: scroll, overflow-x: hidden;

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I have tried it but it does not scroll at all :(

Comment: Wrap listview inside a div, give that div height and properties in my previous comment.

Comment: hi again. I have edit my question with what I think your are saying?  thanks

Comment: For mobile safari you can also include the CSS: -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; (Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Sd4KS/2/ )

Comment: Hi, thanks. That is useful and will implement. Still looking for a Android solution...

Comment: are you willing to solve it using js?

Comment: Of course! Prefer to :)